# Using MongoDB along with ionic android app

Tags: android, mongodb

I am building an android app using the ionicjs framework. I have done the basic layout using ionic's creator that gives me the code for it when I export it.
Now, I have to authenticate the login and register information against the details in the database, which is MongoDB. My question is, how do I install MongoDB? Do I install via the command prompt like it says in the Mongodb website or do a npm install in the root folder of my project?
After the installation, how do I go about connecting to the DB and doing the authentication? I think I need to use a REST API for that. 
It would be very helpful if someone points me in a direction. I am new to developing apps like this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is a server-side database. So you have to install it on a remote machine, You shouldn't connect database directly with the mobile application which runs on clients hand. It's totally insecure, anyone can reveal your database connection information (password, username) by simply decompiling the app.

So, As you figure out, right way is to create a REST API to retrieve and send data back and forth between the server and the application.

Create a backend services with a server-side technology that your are prefer. It could be PHP,Python,Java or whatever. The client side application should not depend on the server-side technology your are using. Server side technology should completely transparent to the client application. You can attain this by designing good REST API.

Comment: Thanks. I installed mongodb locally on my machine and now doing it via npm install. Solving some dependency errors. I will be doing it the REST way. And the backend is node.js, which is using express.

Comment: For further information, just google  "micro service architecture" http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html

Comment: Yes it's true, Microservice not fit for the every requirement. But you can get some insight.  You may already know "service oriented architecture" That why I wanted to point you to a modern approach. But still you need to check the applicability to your project :)

Comment: I have come to the stage where i have installed mongodb using npm and the normal way and i added a collection to it. now im looking at how to configure the db and modify the code to get it to work with the app.

Comment: I have another question related to nodejs. i have been having issues with npm install and i deleted the node_modules folder multiple times before trying to intall npm again. at one point, i deleted the npm cache folder and left the node_modules alone and did the npm install and it worked! im wondering if this would be an issue in the future.